# kernel: imklog Error return from sys_sycall: 1

Tags: 12.04, do-release-upgrade

After an Ubuntu 64 virtual server update from 10.04 to 12.04, I get the log message in `var/log/syslog`:

> kernel: imklog Error return from sys_sycall: 1

It's writing constantly to the log file. `syslog`, `kern.log` and `kern.log.1` has filled up my disk.
So far I just updated the kernel.

Comment: nicoX, were you able to fix this issue? If so, please add an answer describing what you did.

Comment: I'm not sure I remember right. I think we rolled back to 10.04, or did a clean install. There was so many services that where causing issues, as we used to be on 8.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution/workaround that my co-worker who ran into this issue used was to disable the imklog module by running 
`sed -i -e 's/^\$ModLoad imklog/#\$ModLoad imklog/g' /etc/rsyslog.conf` 
as suggested here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/523610/comments/49